# can viewport unit defeniton and browser zooming co-exist

Tags: html, css, zooming, viewport-units

I have a simple html page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="font-size:1vw">text</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

using the vw units is the easiest way to make the page responsive to window resizing on desktop, but it's completely disabling the browser zooming functionality, is there a way that those two can work together ? can I use vw units without disabling the browser zooming functionality ?
thanks

Comment: the zooming option is useful for users with poor eyesight and I'm trying to find out if there is a way to take advantage of this browser build in functionality and in the same time use vw units ?